# Newbie here. How will I validate in the admin page the subjects enrolled will not be duplicated in the entries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Here's my model.py

```
class SubjectsEnrolled(models.Model):
student =  models.ForeignKey(Student)
STATUS = (
    ('1', 'Passed'),
    ('2', 'Failed'),
    ('3', 'No Grade'),
    ('4', 'Incomplete'),
)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
schoolterm = models.ForeignKey(SchoolTerm)

class Meta: 
    verbose_name = _('Subjects Enrolled') 
    verbose_name_plural = _('Subjects Enrolled')
```

Here's my Admin.py

```
class SubjectsEnrolled(models.Model):
student =  models.ForeignKey(Student)
STATUS = (
    ('1', 'Passed'),
    ('2', 'Failed'),
    ('3', 'No Grade'),
    ('4', 'Incomplete'),
)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
schoolterm = models.ForeignKey(SchoolTerm)

class Meta: 
    verbose_name = _('Subjects Enrolled') 
    verbose_name_plural = _('Subjects Enrolled')
```

The student should have a subject in a schoolterm and the subject should not duplicate in a schoolterm.

Comment: Both these code blocks are identical. Can you post the admin code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#unique-together) meta option.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('subject', 'schoolterm')
```

After that validation will perform everywhere, not just in the admin.